# JawsDB error connecting with Heroku

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

I tried to push my project to heroku and connect jawsdb with the application. I input jawsdb info into my server.js and updated it then pushed to heroku. But I'm getting this erorr and the application wont load. I think it has something to do with the way I'm setting up the database.

I am receiving the following "Access denied for user" error:

https://ibb.co/giRO5m

this is my code: server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var logger = require('morgan');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var methodOverride = require('method-override')
var fs = require("fs");
var hbs = require('hbs');
// Set up Express
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

//handlebars
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({defaultLayout:'main'});
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
// override with POST having ?_method=DELETE
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))


// Set up Mysql
var con = mysql.createConnection({

  host: "t89yihg12rw77y6f.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  port: 3306,
  user: "swvr0i1j9ny720mk",
  password: "e3lzkqag4dmeqhup"
});

//conecting to mysql
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database connected to the matrix..");
});

con.query('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS warehouse', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query('USE warehouse', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        con.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS storage('
            + 'id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,'
            + 'PRIMARY KEY(id),'
            + 'link VARCHAR(255),'
            + 'item VARCHAR(255),'
            + 'stock VARCHAR(255)'
            +  ')', function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
    });
});

// Parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// Serve static content for the app from the "public" directory in the application directory.
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


//prints database to page
app.get('/index', function(req,res) {

    con.query('SELECT * FROM storage;', function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;

      //test it
      //console.log('The solution is: ', data);

      //test it
      //res.send(data);

      res.render('index', {storage : data});
    });
});

//delete data entry
app.delete('/delete', function(req,res){
    con.query('DELETE FROM storage WHERE id = ?', [req.body.id], function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.redirect('/index');
    });
});

// Open Server
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

JawsDB does not let you choose the database name or create a new database name. Instead, you will need to connect via a workbench tool and see what the database name they have given you is (for example, the below show my database name JawsDB assigned).

[image: default schema by JawsDB]

Then, use this database in your code instead of the one you named "warehouse." For example, if I were to do this with the schema JawsDB named for me, I would use 'jdjkhrjps1cgj89h'

```
con.query('USE jdjkhrjps1cgj89h', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS storage('
        + 'id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,'
        + 'PRIMARY KEY(id),'
        + 'link VARCHAR(255),'
        + 'item VARCHAR(255),'
        + 'stock VARCHAR(255)'
        +  ')', function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
});
```